# how to get the id of an entry based on the name in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have created the following model in Django to store my groups in a database:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Now I would like to get the id of a group by its name in my views.py. How do I do that?
with the `Group.objects.get()` method I can filter by name, but there I get the whole row without the id.

Comment: You can extract it's pk or id with .id 
i.e.  `instance.id`

Answer (score 1):

You can query like this:

```py
single_object=get_object_or_404(Group,name=any_name)
object_id=single_object.pk
```